# Sort string in Java

Tags: sorting

I need way to sort according to the name .
‏ According to the number of letters of the alphabet, the word starts from A to Z,

‏ it's mean you want to count how many a in the two word and the word who have the largest number of letter a, you want to put this word first (swap)

‏ And if their number of a  is equal, you will compare the letter after it means b, and if the number of the word is equal, you will compare C, and this is what ... and he will tell you that this is the case Suppose that there are no students who are inspired by the same number of all letters in the same class
My Code contains a class contain a name type of string and main drive contain a array of objects

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I'm a C++ and Python Developer. I can't help you with the Java Code, but according to your query, I think Count Sort is the most suitable for this kind of problem
 because while sorting numbers it sorts all of them using their Digits. 

*Example*

Input data: 1, 4, 1, 2, 7, 5, 2

1. Take a count array to store the count of each unique object.
   Index:     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
   Count:     0  2  2  0   1  1  0  1  0  0
2. Modify the count array such that each element at each index
   stores the sum of previous counts.
   Index:     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
   Count:     0  2  4  4  5  6  6  7  7  7

The modified count array indicates the position of each object in
the output sequence.

3. Rotate the array clockwise for one time.
   Index:     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
   Count:     0 0 2 4 4 5 6 6 7 7
4. Output each object from the input sequence followed by
   increasing its count by 1.
   Process the input data: 1, 4, 1, 2, 7, 5, 2. Position of 1 is 0.
   Put data 1 at index 0 in output. Increase count by 1 to place next data 1 at an index 1 greater than this index.

---

Above Example is Taken from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/

Comment: i try this but he did not work

Comment: If you're sorting the names in a dictionary manner. Then It's the only sorting algorithm I think will be useful in every aspect. There is a problem in your code.